How to set automatic count and leave blank rows in vba
can anyone help me with a small problem. I have a report that creates a table when a VBA button is clicked and selects a xlookup from the other two tables, but in the code here Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I300") Range("I2:I300").Select I have set it up for 300 rows but sometimes is 200 sometime 150 and all rest rows in hte table then returned as number 0. Do you know somebody how to set this code ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=XLOOKUP(RC[-7],Route!C[-8],Route!C[14])" and it will count up to 300 but if I will have just 200 rows all rest empties rows in I column will leave as blank not number 0?
`Sub report
Sheets("report1").Select
Rows("1:5").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("A:B").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("F:K").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("I:Q").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Cells.Select
With Selection
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Cases"
Range("I2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=XLOOKUP(RC[-7],Route!C[-8],Route!C[14])"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I300")
Range("I2:I300").Select
Range("A1:J1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Range("A1").Select
Call SendEmail

End Sub`


Improve Macro-Recorder Code: Make a Range Dynamic
Edit!

Shortened the borders code suggested by MGonet!!!



This is far from ideal but couldn't do better with so little information.
I chose column B to determine the last row since that's the column where your formula is looking up values (I - 7 = B).
Also, I assumed that there are headers after the deletion in row 1 which I used to determine the last column.

Sub UpdateReport()
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it isn't, reference it by its name or use 'ActiveWorkbook'.
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Report1")
    
    ' Delete rows and columns and clear the formula column.
    ws.Rows("1:5").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ' Leave `C:G,N:P` and beyond `Z:Z` (inclusive) intact.
    ws.Range("A:B,H:M,Q:Y").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ws.Columns("I").Clear ' (previous column 'Z')
    
    ' Determine the last row based on column 'B' (previous column 'D')
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in column 'B'.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Determine the last column based on the first row.
    Dim LastCol As Long:
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ' Reference the range.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    
    ' Format the range.
    With rg
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
    ' Populate the formula column 'I' (previous column 'Z').
    With rg.Columns("I")
        .Cells(1).Value = "Cases"
        .Cells(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1) _
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=XLOOKUP(RC[-7],Route!C[-8],Route!C[14])"
    End With
    
    ' Format columns 'A:J'.
    With rg.Columns("A:J")
        ' Interior
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        ' Font
        With .Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        End With
        ' Borders
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        With .Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Select the first cell ('A1') (also acitvates the sheet).
    Application.Goto rg.Cells(1)
    
    SendEmail ' ???

End Sub


This will be a step up for someone who has mastered macro recording.

If you apply the same formatting to all edges, formatting the whole thing is sufficient:
With .Borders: .LineStyle = xlContinuous: .ColorIndex = 0: .Weight = xlThin: End With
Only the diagonals need to be formatted separately if they were used.

@MGonet Nice catch. Thanks. 'I knew it'. Now I know why I couldn't figure it out: IntelliSense doesn't work for rg.Columns("A:J"). I should have tried with rg or introduced another variable for rg.Columns("A:J").

Among other solutions, the easiest one for you is:
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-7]),"""",XLOOKUP(RC[-7],Route!C[-8],Route!C[14]))"


But you need to consider VBasic2008's answer.
